# Firefox form elements not behaving correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, frontend

I have a very simple list of four elements, each with a checkbox.

I have an jQuery ajax request which returns the status of these tasks and if they have been completed, puts a tick in the checkbox.

The code is very simple

`task` is the task name, for example task_1, task_2 etc

```
if(data.task.task_status === 1) {
    $('input[data-task="'+task+'"]').attr('checked','checked');
}
```

This code works as it should in all browsers except Firefox, and its not the first time I have had issues with Firefox and forms. My understanding is Firefox 'remembers' form data so if you refresh the page you don't lose textarea data etc. Is it something to do with this?

Comment: There's no reason those lines of code would not work in Firefox, although `prop('checked', true)` would be better practice. The issue must be somewhere else in the logic which you've not shown. I'd suggest checking the console for errors as a first step in debugging this

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'd be curios what `console.log(task)` outputs. But I don't see how, if it was an object, it would work in Chrome or any other browser. Without viewing the bug first hand it's impossible to say.

Comment: and unless you have other reasons, code it like `$('input[data-task='+task+']').prop('checked',data.task.task_status === 1);`

Comment: What is weird is `$('input[data-welcome-task="task_3"]').attr('checked','checked');` <-- this works when I load the page and grab all tasks to update the checkboxes. But, only `$('input[data-welcome-task="task_3"]').prop('checked', true);` works if its an onClick?